# How to update dependencies in Package.json

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install, package.json

If you are having a bunch of packages which are the older version. And if you already tried to update through npm install and it didn't work. Below is one of the easiest solutions

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, then at least phrase the question so that it is actually answered by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Visual Studio Code as your IDE, this is a fun little extension to make updating package.json a one click process.

Version Lense
[image]